# What tag should be used for questions related to non-christians?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

Right now we have [unbelievers](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unbelievers), [unsaved](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unsaved), and [non-christian](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/non-christian).  None of them have very many questions, but I still hesitate to eliminate two of them without a bit of discussion.  Here are the kinds of questions in, um, question:

- [Is it generally acceptable to attend a bible study as a non Christian?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/25372/21576)
- [Can the Word of God and God's wisdom be beneficial to an unbeliever?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/4976/21576)
- [How to interpret the ban of unions between believers and non-believers?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/19485/21576)

Some of the other questions associated with these tags may not actually need it, but it seems to me that one tag of this type is worth keeping.  Which one?

Comment: I would question whether the questions in question are questions that raise a question about the site's taxonomy of questions.

Comment: non-christian**s** would probably be the best tag. unbelievers generally still believe things, and unsaved is a judgement call that should be avoided in tags if possible.

Comment: It would strictly leave the ridiculous self-identified 'atheist Christians' out of the group referred to by the tag, but there are so few questions about them it doesn't matter.

Comment: @curiousdannii Technically I think all three of them would exclude 'atheist Christians' since they describe themselves as 'Christian.' So to tag such questions we should use the existing athiest tag or a new atheist-christian tag if the need arises.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We should keep [non-christian](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/non-christian), as it is the most specific of the three, *rename it to* [non-christians](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/non-christians) (*plural*), and the others should be made synonyms of it.

Comment: While I agree that non-christian should be the preferred term & will be applicable in most contexts, the other terms have a different shade of meaning that may be more applicable in certain contexts. eg: "Certain Evangelicals believe that it's possible to be a 'Christian' and yet unsaved, what is the basis for such a belief?" etc.

Comment: @bruisedreed Such a distinction would be perfectly fine for a question title or body to build on, but as far as a taxonomy goes I think it's fair enough to tag all such questions with the same tag.

Comment: I agree, but think the plural non-christians would be best.

Comment: @curiousdannii Not sure if this is a trivial enough update to be included in this answer, but I'm hoping so.  `Non-christians` it is.